# If a player has 3 goals, but one of them is own goal, is it called a hat trick?

Tags: statistics, own-goal

To put it simply: do own goals count as part of a hat trick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually a Hat-Trick is an informal term, and can be defined by whoever is speaking/writing. So if it was a team-mate you might go for humour and say "Our Striker scored a hat-trick .... but unfortunately one was at the wrong end".

And a journalist might call it "[an imperfect hat-trick](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-2261884/Jon-Walters-scored-goals--players-WORSE.html)" , or a special hat-trick, or a hat-trick by majority verdict, or a hat-trick of sorts, or whatever they feel best fits.

But if this term ever needs to be defined in an official way, maybe as part of a sponsor's prize, or for betting, then I'm sure the answer will be no. For example, the betting exchange [Betfair defines](http://www.betfair.com/aboutUs/Sportsbook.Rules.And.Regulations/#sportsbookpartc) it like this:

> For ‘Tournament Hat-trick’ markets, extra-time is included, however penalty shoot-outs and **own goals are not included**. In the event of any dispute as to who has scored any goal we will follow the decision made by the relevant governing body.